# How to display article from category and show it in block

Tags: views, blocks

I have created a content type which has some fields, and I want these fields to be displayed as a block.

I need to display some article like 5 articles from category called sport news only.

how can i do that in drupal 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure of your exact need, between articles, your content type... Try something like that :

Go to **admin/structure/views/add**.
Fill in the form : Show Content of type *article* (or *Your content type*). If  *sport news* is a taxonomy category, tagged with *sport news*.

Uncheck *create page*, check *create a block*, display format *table of fields*, five items, then continue and edit.

Now in the left side of the form, click on add fields, choose the fields you'd like to display and settings for each field. Give a admin name to your block in Block settings, at the top of the middle column. You now have a block view with 5 items of content type article and the fields you selected.

[image]

Go to **admin/structure/block**, look for the block you've just created, and set the region where you'd like to display it, or click on configure to be more specific, displaying it on specific pages, for specific roles or whatever.

Comment: very nice, ok i do that and i tag sport news in views but its display article from sport news and from world news why ??

Comment: I added a screen capture of the view edit page. If your filter is Content : Has taxonomy term ( = Sport news ), you shouldn't see articles tagged world news, except if these articles are tagged with both terms.

Answer (score -1):

You must install the views plugin. After installing the plugin, you can go to structure-view-add a view to make a list of posts with condition that the content type is of specific criteria and set the display type to be a block. After that go to the block setting and set region the block belongs to.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers. This is an old question that already has an acceped answer, which means the problem is already solved.  However, please note that there is no such thing in Drupal as a "views plugin".  You're probably talking about the Views *module*, but it will not do anything like you suggest by itself.  To add a view like you suggest, you need to also install the **Views UI** module.  Please delete or correct your answer.